# Variables not changing it's values - Function returning promise - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, sqlite, react-native

So I'm making a function for every time I need to work with my database SQLite I give to this function 3 parameters and then it returns for me the result.

The problem is the function is returning a promise, and also I tried to update the value of some variables and they don't change:

Let me show you my code, and then to explain you better about what I'm having trouble with:

```
       //Down here I'm using the function I made, I'm passing as parameters my  
       // connection, my SQL string, and my arguments

        (Main.js)
        const resultSQL = sqlExecute(db,'SELECT * FROM tbl_diarys',[]);
        console.log(resultSQL)

----- // Now this down here is the function I made------------------------------------------------------

      const { Alert } = require("react-native")

      const sqlExecute = async (dbConection,sqlQuery,arg,)=> {

      let resultSQL = []
      let test = 'x' // variable that i created to make a test changing it's value  
          

           await dbConection.transaction((tx)=>{
              tx.executeSql(sqlQuery,arg,(tx,results)=>
               {
                Alert.alert('', 'SQL executed with success')

                  var len = results.rows.length;
                  var vectorResults = []

                  for (let i=0; i<len; i++){
                  let row = results.rows.item(i);
                  vectorResults.push(row)
                  }

            console.log(vectorResults) // Showing the results from my database

            test = 'y' // trying to change the value of variable "test"  from 'x' to 'y'

            resultSQL = [...vectorResults]; // cloning my results from database to my variable resultSQL

        },(error)=>{Alert.alert('Some error had happened'); console.log(error)})
    })


    console.log(test) // showing the value of my variable "test"

    console.log(resultSQL) // showing the value of my variable resultSQL

    return (resultSQL);
    
}

module.exports=sqlExecute
```

THIS IS MY CONSOLE.LOG
[this is a picture of my console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LJAh.jpg) <----------------------------------

So my questions are:

1º Why my variable "test" never changed it's value to 'y'?

2º Why my function is returning a promise? since I put to return the variable resultSQL?

3º Why my variable `resultSQL` also never changed it's value to my database results?

As you guys can see my connection with the database is working well returning a vector with results of my SQL query, but I can't manage to return this vector, instead my function is returning a promise.

Thank you guys for helping me, I wish you all a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look into how async/await works. In the background they use promises, so that anwers your second question. That's why your method returns a promise, because it's an async method.

To answer your other 2 questions. It seems like the `tx.executeSql()` and `dbConnection.transaction()` methods work with callbacks, but you don't wait for the callbacks to be called and resume executing your code. This is why you think that your variable `test` and `resultSQL` aren't changing. They do actually change, but you're calling the `console.log` before they change.

I would recommend changing your `sqlExecute` method from async to a promise (I think it's easier to understand for beginners). It would become something like this:

```js
const sqlExecute = (dbConection,sqlQuery,arg,)=> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let resultSQL = []
        let test = 'x' // variable that i created to make a test changing it's value  
          
        dbConection.transaction((tx)=>{
            tx.executeSql(sqlQuery,arg,(tx,results)=>
            {
                Alert.alert('', 'SQL executed with success');

                var len = results.rows.length;
                var vectorResults = []

                for (let i=0; i<len; i++){
                    let row = results.rows.item(i);
                    vectorResults.push(row)
                }

                console.log(vectorResults) // Showing the results from my database

                test = 'y' // trying to change the value of variable "test"  from 'x' to 'y'

                resultSQL = [...vectorResults]; // cloning my results from database to my variable resultSQL

                console.log(test) // showing the value of my variable "test"

                console.log(resultSQL) // showing the value of my variable resultSQL

                resolve(resultSQL);

            },(error)=>{
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
}

// Call sqlExecute as a promise, for example
sqlExecute(connection, query, arg).then(()=>{
    console.log('We did it!');
}).catch((error)=>{
    Alert.alert('Some error had happened');
    console.log(error);
});
```

As I said, your code could become "something like this". I give no guarantees this exact code works and you'll have to clean it up a little.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked well, i can see that, i still have a lot to learn about Async/Await and Promises !. I'm using your code to understand how to create and use my own promises ! I will make sure to study more about this async methods. Thank you again for you help !